# Can Apex Install Non-Virtual Resources via Assimilator?

Tags: android-netrunner

Apex has the abilities:

> You cannot install non-virtual resources.
>
> When your turn begins, you may install 1 card from your grip facedown.

Assimilator says:

> [click], [click]: Turn one of your facedown installed cards faceup. If that card is an event, trash it.

Can I install a non-virtual resource face down using Apex's second ability and then turn it face up with Assimilator?

The second sentence of Assimilator indicates that Apex's second ability allows you to install things that you couldn't normally install, such as events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  First, you can include non-virtual resources in your deck, since there is no restriction on this.  Then, the rules reference says the following on facedown runner cards:

> Runner cards that are installed or turned facedown do not have a name, type, or subtypes, and their abilities are not active.

Since you are installing the resource facedown, it is not a resource and thus not subject to Apex's install restriction.

Finally, turning it face up with Assimilator is not an installation, so is also not subject to Apex's restriction.  Support for this can be found in the rules reference:

> Turning an installed facedown Runner card faceup does 
>   not trigger install effects